# How to serialize data into indented json

Tags: c#, json, file

I am using this code to serialize the users into `json` text file.

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    using (var file = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(file, this.users);
    }
}
```

This is the result that I get :

[[image: output]]

How can I get a result like this :

[[image: pretty-print]]

Comment: Why do you need to create a "beutiful file"?

Comment: Is this [`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonserializer.htm)?

Comment: In no conceivable definition of `url-rewriting` is that tag applicable.

Answer (score 25):

Set the formatting on the serializer to Indented.

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
serializer.Serialize(file, this.users);
```

Answer (score 18):

Use this instead :

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    using (var file = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.users, Formatting.Indented);
        file.Write(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: May as well write directly to the IO stream over to memory and then out, but Formatting.Indented is spot on.

Comment: @JonathonChase True, your solution is definitively better. Also, less modification for OP. Have an upvote~